# Deploy Failed in GlassFish Server 3

Tags: java, netbeans, build, glassfish

I'm working on a Webapplication. I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1, Java, JSF and GlassFish Server 3.

If I try to deploy the project I get following error:

```
    init:
    deps-module-jar:
    deps-ear-jar:
    deps-jar:
    library-inclusion-in-archive:
    library-inclusion-in-manifest: 
    compile:
    compile-jsps:
    In-place deployment at /home/ghost/Dokumente/fontys/s2/prj2/trunk/realisierun/program/prj2-m2-10b/build/web
    deploy?path=/home/ghost/Dokumente/fontys/s2/prj2/trunk/realisierung/program/prj2m2-10b/build/web&name=prj2-m2-10b&force=true on GlassFish Server 3 failed
    /home/ghost/Dokumente/fontys/s2/prj2/trunk/realisierung/program/prj2-m2-10/nbproject/build-impl.xml:784: The module has not been deployed.
    BUILD FAILED
```

But cleaning and building works fine. I could not find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: you should check your glassfish logs. the netbeans output doesnt report the exceptions.

Comment: You might export WAR file from Netbeans and deploy it with GF Admin portal (by default: localhost:4848, login: admin, password - if domain is created by NetBeans: anonymous), then we'll see if the problem is in NetBeans or in WAR itself.

Comment: @atlanis
How can I deploy with GlassFish Admin Portal?

Comment: Refer to GlassFish documentation: http://glassfish.java.net/docs/3.1/quick-start-guide.pdf page 10

Answer (score 1):

If my Glassfish behaves crazy, I do:

- stop GF,
- delete /domain1/generated/*,
- delete /domain1/osgi-cache/*,
- start GF.

Comment: How did you come up with that solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just restart the server all will be fine.